# How to rename a single file in a folder to the exact folder name, leaving the file extension as is?

Tags: linux, rename

I have hundreds of folders with a single video file. I need to change the video file name to match exactly the folder name, leaving the extension as is. For example:

```
/home/username/Videos/My Video File 1/some.video.file.name.mp4
```

would change to

```
/home/username/Videos/My Video File 1/My Video File 1.mp4
```

Ideally the process would run in the "Videos" folder to handle all of the "My Video File 1,2,3,...etc" folders and included files.

I have installed "rename", and use several examples such as:

```
rename -v 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1/' */*
```

This prepends the folder name properly, but leaves the appended file name I want to replace. I just do not know how to modify it to do that.

---

**UPDATE**: To perform a controlled test, I have setup two folders in the Videos folder, each folder containing a single video file. The folder and file names show the way the video file names are formatted, with a variety of spaces, dots, dashes, underscores, and parenthesis. The folder names are clean except for many with spaces and parentheses with the date of the video inside.

When I run the script provided in the answer above, I get this result:

```
~/Videos$ for ext in mp4 avi mkv; do for     file in $(find /home/username/Videos -name "*.$ext"); do dir=$(dirname $file); fn=$(basename $dir); mv $file $dir/$fn. $ext; done; done
```

I get this result:

```
mv: target 'mp4' is not a directory
mv: target 'mp4' is not a directory
mv: target 'mp4' is not a directory
mv: target 'mp4' is not a directory
mv: target 'mkv' is not a directory
mv: target 'mkv' is not a directory
mv: target 'mkv' is not a directory
```

Using the "tree" command, here are the contents of the two video folders:

```
Videos
├── Disneyland
│   └── Disneyland 720P H265-One.mkv
└── The Family Video (2020)
    └── The.Family.Video.(2020).720P.H265-One.mp4
```

The script should produce these results when run in the Video folder:

```
Videos
├── Disneyland
│   └── Disneyland.mkv
└── The Family Video (2020)
    └── The Family Video (2020).mp4
```

I suspect the spaces in the folder names to be some of the problems, but it looks like there is more given the 'mv:' error messages.

Comment: “Apologies for the lack of block/code formatting. I tried several approaches, none seemed to 'stick'.” Code formatting is simple. Just look at the Control Strip above the edit box when you are editing. Just select the code and the click the code formatting option. Short if that, just add 4 spaces in front of any code text. Look at [my edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1815484/revisions) to learn more.

Comment: "hundreds of folders with a single video file" – Please clarify. Should we assume that (1A) any directory (`Video` or below) that contains at least one regular file contains exactly one regular file and this is a video file to be renamed? Or (1B) for every directory should we check if there is exactly one regular file and only then rename it? Or (1C) for every directory should we check if there is exactly one video file and only then rename it? Video file by "extension"? by content? (2) In a directory with a "matching" file, should nonexistence of subdirectories matter?

Comment: Each directory may have more than one file, but will only have one video file (mkv, mp4, or avi). Video files are defined by the extension. Other extension types are to be ignored. I want that one file's name to match its directory name, leaving the extension as is. Directory names, and therefore the modified file names, may contain spaces and parentheses, as shown in the tree example above. Thank you.

Comment: "Each directory may have more than one file, but will only have one video file" – In your example this does not apply to `Videos` though. (3) Do we need to check only direct subdirectories of `Videos`? or directories at any level?

Comment: Note: clarifications (including replies to my comments that ask for clarifications) should be edited into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the possible extensions, a simple bash command-line would do this:

```
for ext in mp4 mpg avi mkv; do for file in $(find /home/username/Videos -name "*.$ext"); do dir=$(dirname $file); fn=$(basename $dir); mv $file $dir/$fn.$ext; done; done
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer, but I utterly hate shell scripts where they are compressed onto one line as a “one liner.” Ridiculous. There should be line breaks in there to basic readability.

Comment: Well, 'simple' it may be to some, but if it solves my problem I am willing to wade through it, formatting aside, and test it. I will report back on how it goes.

Comment: [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).